redhat + DELL + Controller reset is requested due to IO timeout
We have a DELL server with iDRAC (Integrated Dell Remote Access Controller). Usually, hardware problems related to controllers, storage, or disks are viewed through iDRAC. However, in our case, we see that the Red Hat Linux kernel is reporting the message as - Controller reset is requested due to IO timeout, while iDRAC does not show anything.
I wonder why the kernel is more sensitive than iDRAC and how serious these messages are.
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 07 22 b2 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: task abort: FAILED scmd(ffffa06725a9f700)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 task abort called for scmd(ffffa04002669880)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 07 23 c0 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: task abort: FAILED scmd(ffffa04002669880)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 task abort called for scmd(ffffa03ff4c378c0)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 14 80 01 08 00 00 00 08 00 00
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: task abort: FAILED scmd(ffffa03ff4c378c0)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 task abort called for scmd(ffffa0400266ad80)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 07 23 d8 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: task abort: FAILED scmd(ffffa0400266ad80)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#3 task abort called for scmd(ffffa03ff4c35940)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#3 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 15 c1 91 08 00 00 00 10 00 00
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: task abort: FAILED scmd(ffffa03ff4c35940)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 task abort called for scmd(ffffa0400266f540)
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 07 23 ea 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[Wed Nov 27 14:12:24 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: task abort: FAILED scmd(ffffa0400266f540)
[Wed Nov 27 14:14:10 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: target reset called for scmd(ffffa06725a9e580)
[Wed Nov 27 14:14:10 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 megasas: target reset FAILED!!
[Wed Nov 27 14:14:10 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 Controller reset is requested due to IO timeout


I dlet6e the post  unix.stackexchange.com/questions/787460/… so you can answer here

Vote retracted for this question

ok now I will be happy to hear what you have to say

This is pure speculation and I add it as comment. For me this problem you see in kernel logs is based on write and (probably) the error is recovered. And because of this it do not change SMART parameters. And IMHO iDRAC monitor exactly SMART to report for problems with disks. Again, this is pure speculation :)
